# What is the correct way to extract data from second table relationship in blade view

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

In my route.php I defined the group route resource:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin|staff|retailer|customer|spy'],     
function()
{
  Route::resource('profiles', 'ProfileController');
});
```

My User.php model contains this relationship

```
public function address ()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'user_id');
}
```

My Address.php model contains this relationship

```
public function user ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In my ProfileController.php, I have a REST method called edit() that sends $user variable to view blade

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $user = Auth::user();
   return view('profiles.edit')->with('user',$user);
}
```

Now here is the thing: This is my /view/profiles/edit.blade.php. Just sample of 2 fields of editing:

```
{!! Form::model($user, [
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'route' => ['profiles.update', $user->id]
    ]) !!}
   <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('lblfirst_name', 'First Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('lbladdress_line1', 'Address line 1:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('address_line1', $user->address->address_line1, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Notice the

```
$user->address->address_line1
```

Currently this is how I'm extracting data from the address table and using this way, I found out there is 1 extra sql query that this form doing:

```
select * from addresses where addresses.user_id = '1' and addresses.user_id is not null limit 1
```

My question is, is there a better way of doing this ? I mean without doing extra query like how I extracted the First Name field above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when You call **Auth::user()** it does:

vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $identifier
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    return $this->createModel()->newQuery()->find($identifier);
}
```

it gets User model and does ->find($id), so even You change behaviour of find() function You have to send second request to retrieve related data. It's way how Eloquent does.

Only thing You can do is to cache second query:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$address = Cache::remember('users::'.$user->id.'::address', 10, function() use ($user) {
    return Address::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
});
return view('profiles.edit', compact('user', 'address'));
```

Comment: Hai @num8er thanks for the answer and explanation! Does laravel 5.1 supports remember caching? I read that the cache manager has been removed since 5.0. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oops... sorry I've forgot about it. You're right it's been removed. (: